# Using left join with min

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, min

I am trying to connect two tables with left join and a date.

**My SQL Query**

```
SELECT
    ord.`ordernumber` bestellnummer,
    his.`change_date` zahldatum
FROM
    `s_order` ord
LEFT JOIN
    `s_order_history` his ON ((ord.`id`=his.`orderID`) AND (ord.`cleared`=his.`payment_status_id`)) #AND MIN(his.`change_date`)
WHERE
    ord.`ordertime` >= \''.$dateSTART.'\' AND ord.`ordertime`  <= \''.$dateSTOP.'\'' ;
```

**s_order**

```
+----+---------------------+---------+-------------+
| id |     ordertime       | cleared | ordernumber |
+----+---------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | 2014-08-11 19:53:43 |       2 |         123 |
|  2 | 2014-08-15 18:33:34 |       2 |         125 |
+----+---------------------+---------+-------------+
```

**s_order_history**

```
+----+-------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+
| id | payment_status_id | order_status_id | orderID | orderID change_date |
+----+-------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |                 1 |               5 |       1 | 2014-08-11 20:53:43 |
|  2 |                 2 |               5 |       1 | 2014-08-11 22:53:43 |
|  3 |                 2 |               7 |       1 | 2014-08-12 19:53:43 |
|  4 |                 1 |               5 |       2 | 2014-08-15 18:33:34 |
|  5 |                 1 |               6 |       2 | 2014-08-16 18:33:34 |
|  6 |                 2 |               6 |       2 | 2014-08-17 18:33:34 |
+----+-------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+
```

**Wanted result:**

```
+-------------+---------------------+
| ordernumber |     change_date     |
+-------------+---------------------+
|         123 | 2014-08-11 22:53:43 |
|         125 | 2014-08-17 18:33:34 |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

The problem I have is getting only the date, where the cleared/payment_status_id value has been changed in s_order. I currently get all dates where the payment_status_id matches the current cleared value, but I only need the one, where it happend first.

This is only an excerpt of the actually query, since the original is a lot longer (mostly more left joins and a lot more tables).

Comment: Do you want this:  
`SELECT a.ordernumber,b.change_date FROM s_order a,s_order_history b WHERE (a.id = b.order_ID) AND (a.cleared = b.payment_status_id)`

I'm not getting what you want in MIN() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group data by `ordernumber`

```
SELECT
    ord.`ordernumber` bestellnummer,
    MIN(his.`min_change_date`) as zahldatum
FROM
    `s_order` ord
LEFT JOIN
    `s_order_history` his ON ((ord.`id`=his.`orderID`) AND (ord.`cleared`=his.`payment_status_id`)) #AND MIN(his.`change_date`)
WHERE
    ord.`ordertime` >= \''.$dateSTART.'\' AND ord.`ordertime`  <= \''.$dateSTOP.'\''
GROUP BY 
    ord.`ordernumber`;
```

or you can group data in a subquery:

```
SELECT
    ord.`ordernumber` bestellnummer,
    his.`min_change_date` zahldatum
FROM
    `s_order` ord
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
       orderID, payment_status_id, MIN(change_date) as min_change_date
    FROM
        s_order_history
    GROUP BY
        orderID, payment_status_id
) his ON (ord.`id` = his.`orderID` AND ord.`cleared` = his.`payment_status_id`)
WHERE
    ord.`ordertime` >= \''.$dateSTART.'\' AND ord.`ordertime`  <= \''.$dateSTOP.'\'';
```

Comment: Grouping the data solved the problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

MIN is an aggregate function so you can't use it in a JOIN straight up like you've tried above. You also are not comparing it to a value in your JOIN.

You'll want to do something like:

```
his.`change_date` = (SELECT MIN(his.`change_date`) FROM s_order_history where ord.`id` = his.`orderID`)
```

in your `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select s_order.ordernumber, min(s_order_history.change_date)
from s_order left join s_order_history
on s_order.id = s_order_history.orderID
   and s_order.cleared = s_order_history.payment_status_id
group by s_order.order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ord.`ordernumber` bestellnummer,
MIN( his.`change_date` ) zahldatum
...
GROUP BY ord.`ordernumber`
```